# How I can delete all keys that cointain ProgramName?

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, windows-registry, vbscript

How to delete all folders(path) that contain key with a name that contain "ProgramName1"?
CCleaner and programs like that doesn't help. I google for bat,vbs scripts but they scan only HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but I need to scan all register. Also I need this to work on Windows XP, 7 and 10.
Where I can find such a program or script ?
If there is no available scripts like this, at least I need to delete keys that contain "ProgramName1" in all register. All scripts that I found scan only for LOCAL_MACHINE

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try with this vbscript for searching a string in the whole of the registry :

```
'RegSrch.vbs - Search Registry for input string and display results.
'© Bill James - wgjames@mvps.org
' revised 20 Apr 2001 (parses regfile ~3X faster)
' revised 13 Dec 2001 (added Regedit command line switch for Win2K/WindXP)
' Added a waiting bar in HTA because the search can take a while to end by Hackoo on 22/09/2019
Option Explicit
Dim oWS : Set oWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Temp : Temp = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")

Dim sSearchFor
sSearchFor = InputBox("This script will search your Registry and find all " & _
             "instances of the search string you input."  & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
             "This search could take several minutes, so please be patient." & _
             vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Enter search string (case insensitive) and " & _
             "click OK...", WScript.ScriptName & " " & Chr(169) & " Bill James")

If sSearchFor = "" Then Cleanup()

Dim StartTime : StartTime = Timer
Dim sRegTmp, eRegLine, iCnt, sRegKey, aRegFileLines, sOutAdd, sOutRemove, OutAdd, OutRemove
Dim TitreWaitBar,MsgAttente,oExec,Duration
TitreWaitBar = "Please be patient... Scanning the registry for the string " & DblQuote(sSearchFor)
MsgAttente = "Searching for this string " & DblQuote(sSearchFor) &_
" on the whole of the registry"
Call CreateProgressBar(TitreWaitBar,MsgAttente)
Call LancerProgressBar()

sRegTmp = oWS.Environment("Process")("Temp") & "\RegTmp.tmp"
sOutAdd = oWS.Environment("Process")("Temp") & "\sOutAdd" & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now) & ".reg"
sOutRemove = oWS.Environment("Process")("Temp") & "\sOutRemove" & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now) & ".reg"

oWS.Run "regedit /e /a " & sRegTmp, , True '/a enables export as Ansi for WinXP

set OutAdd = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutAdd, 8, True)
set OutRemove = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutRemove, 8, True)

OutAdd.WriteLine("REGEDIT4" & vbcrlf & "; " & WScript.ScriptName & " " & _
    Chr(169) & " Bill James" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "; Registry search " & _
    "results for string " & Chr(34) & sSearchFor & Chr(34) & " " & Now & _
    vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "; NOTE: This file will be deleted when you close " & _
    "WordPad." & vbcrlf & "; You must manually save this file to a new " & _
    "location if you want to refer to it again later." & vbcrlf & "; (If " & _
    "you save the file with a .reg extension, you can use it to restore " & _
    "any Registry changes you make to these values.)" & vbcrlf)

OutRemove.WriteLine("REGEDIT4" & vbcrlf & "; " & WScript.ScriptName & " " & _
    Chr(169) & " Bill James" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "; Registry search " & _
    "results for string " & Chr(34) & sSearchFor & Chr(34) & " " & Now & _
    vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "; NOTE: This file will be deleted when you close " & _
    "WordPad." & vbcrlf & "; You must manually save this file to a new " & _
    "location if you want to refer to it again later." & vbcrlf & "; (If " & _
    "you save the file with a .reg extension, you can use it to restore " & _
    "any Registry changes you make to these values.)" & vbcrlf)

With oFSO.GetFile(sRegTmp)
  aRegFileLines = Split(.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0).Read(.Size), vbcrlf)
End With

oFSO.DeleteFile(sRegTmp)

For Each eRegLine in aRegFileLines
  If InStr(1, eRegLine, "[", 1) > 0 Then sRegKey = eRegLine
  If InStr(1, eRegLine, sSearchFor, 1) >  0 Then
    If sRegKey <> eRegLine Then
      OutAdd.WriteLine(vbcrlf & sRegKey) & vbcrlf & eRegLine
      OutRemove.WriteLine(vbcrlf & "[-" & mid(sRegKey,2)) & vbcrlf & eRegLine
    Else
      OutAdd.WriteLine(vbcrlf & sRegKey)
      OutRemove.WriteLine(vbcrlf & "[-" & mid(sRegKey,2))
    End If
    iCnt = iCnt + 1
  End If
Next

Erase aRegFileLines
Duration = FormatNumber(Timer - StartTime, 0)

If iCnt < 1 Then
  oWS.Popup "Search completed in " & convertTime(Duration) & _
            vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "No instances of " & chr(34) & sSearchFor & chr(34) & _
            " found.",, WScript.ScriptName & " " & Chr(169) & " Bill James", 4096
  .Close
  oFSO.DeleteFile(sOutTmp)
  Cleanup()
End If

OutAdd.Close
OutRemove.Close
Call FermerProgressBar()

oWS.Popup "Search completed in " & convertTime(Duration) & _
          vbcrlf & vbcrlf & iCnt & " instances of " & chr(34) & sSearchFor & chr(34) & _
          " found." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Click OK to open Results in WordPad.",, _
          WScript.ScriptName & " " & Chr(169) & " Bill James", 4096

oWS.Run "WordPad " & sOutAdd, 3, True
oWS.Run "WordPad " & sOutRemove, 3, True

Cleanup()

Sub Cleanup()
  Set oWS = Nothing
  Set oFSO = Nothing
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
'***********************************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Titre,MsgAttente)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Titre & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & MsgAttente &"</font></marquee>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
    fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 490,110"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
    Set oExec = oWS.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Function convertTime(seconds)
    Dim ConvSec,ConvHour,ConvMin
   ConvSec = seconds Mod 60
   If Len(ConvSec) = 1 Then
         ConvSec = "0" & ConvSec
   End If
   ConvMin = (seconds Mod 3600) \ 60
   If Len(ConvMin) = 1 Then
         ConvMin = "0" & ConvMin
   End If
   ConvHour =  seconds \ 3600
   If Len(ConvHour) = 1 Then
         ConvHour = "0" & ConvHour
   End If
   convertTime = ConvHour & ":" & ConvMin & ":" & ConvSec
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: After a few years using your code suggestions on many websites / posts. It is natural for me to sometimes think that you are a type of reptilians! For sure!